# Is there a way to use value from type as a defaultProp in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following type definition:

```js
type Size = "m" | "s"
```

I have a functional component `Thing`

I would like to set the default prop `size` in the spirit of the following:

```
Thing.defaultProps = {
 size: Size[0]
}
```

This code tells me that I am trying to use type as a value. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: TypeScript typings are compile time checks. Setting a value is a runtime operation. You can't really mix the two. You could probably achieve something similar by using an enum instead of a type union though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this by using enums instead. eg:

```js
enum Size {
  M = "m"
  s = "s"
}

Thing.defaultProps = {
   size: Size.M
}
```

With an enum, you can set a variable to be a type of enum, and also the value. Using type is just a definition of the variable